# Is It Possible to Access the Entire 64KB of the Global Data Sharea (GDS) on AMD's GCN2+ GPU's?

Tags: assembly, gpgpu, amd-gcn

I am trying to use the Global Data Share (GDS) on AMD RX 480 for my application either on Linux or Windows. Although the GCN3 Specification Manual states that you can access the GDS without restrictions by setting an appropriate value to the m0 register and issuing Data Share instructions with the GDS bit on, that has not been the case in my experience. More specifically, you cannot access the GDS on Windows at all, and only 4KB is available at a time on Linux. Is there any way to lift this nonsensical restriction at all? Please refer to the following thread for the context of this question:

https://community.amd.com/thread/210432